# Panic button app that specify emergency type

Tags: gps, mobile, communication

Can anyone recommend a panic button app for a mobile device that allows you to choose the type of emergency and instructed the receivers of the distress call what to do.

For example:

- In the case of a medical emergency, any one first first aid experience must immediately come and assist or alternatively call an ambulance.
- In the case of a fire, the receiver should call the fire brigade as the person who pushed the button might have his hands full to evacuate everyone and don't have time for phone calls.
- In the case of a fright, someone heard or saw something specious. No proof that there are any real danger, but you need to notify the neighbours to be on standby just in case.
- The the case of a real armed robbery, you DO NOT want the receivers to call back or come over to look what is going on. You want them to stay as far away as possible and call the police/security.

Note: I am in South Africa.

Comment: What country are you in? I know of [one specific Dutch Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.helpapp.android) that does something like this. ([Website](http://help-app.nl/))

Comment: @JanDoggen - The OPs information says that they are in South Africa.

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes, that is what I am looking for except that it is not available in South Africa.

Comment: As you can see (?) this app was developed/initiated by a first aid organization ([Orange cross](http://www.hetoranjekruis.nl/)). Maybe you can enroll a SA one to do the same?

Comment: I am actually considering it. I just want to make sure that I don't reinvent the wheel.